# Synapse Analytics: Can I execute a synapse pipeline (defined in the workspace) from ADF v2 pipeline

Tags: azure-synapse

Some activities like execute Notebook (Synapse Notebook) and Spark Job are available for Synapse pipelines (ADF in Synapse) but not in ADF v2 - Is there a way to use an activity to execute Synapse pipeline from ADFv2 pipeline? (Web Activity ?)...

Answer (score 0):

> In ADF or Synapse, If you want to run one pipeline from another
> pipeline then you  can make use of execute pipeline activity.
>
> But if you want to run Pipeline in Synapse from Another Azure  data
> factory, then you can consider making REST API call to execute that
> pipeline.

You can leverage Web activity to make a REST API in Azure data factory.

Answer (score 0):

Conceptually similar to a REST call, but I would recommend using an Azure Function. You'll need to use the [Synapse Artifacts SDK](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.Analytics.Synapse.Artifacts/1.0.0-preview.10?_src=template). It is in Preview but works fine and is easy to use. Once you get past the authentication, it is literally create a [PipelineClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.analytics.synapse.artifacts.pipelineclient?view=azure-dotnet-preview) and call [CreatePipelineRun](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.analytics.synapse.artifacts.pipelineclient.createpipelinerun?view=azure-dotnet-preview#Azure_Analytics_Synapse_Artifacts_PipelineClient_CreatePipelineRun_System_String_System_String_System_Nullable_System_Boolean__System_String_System_Collections_Generic_IDictionary_System_String_System_Object__System_Threading_CancellationToken_).